# Data Constructor Limitations

Tags: haskell

I have data structures as such:

`data IfTree = If Expr Statement IfTree | Else Statement | EndIf`

`data Statement = IfStatement IfTree`

What is want is to make it impossible to do any of these combinations:

```
IfStatement $ Else ...
IfStatement $ EndIf
```

An `IfStatement` should only be able to take an `If`.

I am aware that I can hide the data constructors and only expose functions that compose them behind the scenes, but I want to limit this at the data type.

**Update:**

What I was trying to do was clunky. Thanks to the excellent answers and comments, a MUCH better way of handling this was given:

`data Statement = If Expr Statement (Maybe Statement) | ...`

or even:

`data Stat = IfStat Expr Stat | IfElseStat Expr Stat Stat | …`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be the traditional way of doing it:

```
data Stat = IfStat Expr Stat (Maybe Stat) | BarStat | BazStat | …
data Expr = FooExpr | …

-- if (foo) bar;
IfStat FooExpr BarStat Nothing

-- if (foo) bar; else baz;
IfStat FooExpr BarStat (Just BazStat)
```

The idea is to encode the grammar of your language as a data type, or at least the important bits. `Else` and `EndIf` don’t make sense outside of an `If`, so you don’t actually need to represent them.

You can inline the `Maybe` into the statement data type:

```
data Stat = IfStat Expr Stat | IfElseStat Expr Stat Stat | …
```

Or, if it makes sense for your language, you can add a representation for empty statements:

```
data Stat = IfStat Expr Stat Stat | EmptyStat | …

-- if (foo) bar;
-- if (foo) bar; else;
IfStat FooExpr BarStat EmptyStat

-- if (foo) bar; else baz;
IfStat FooExpr BarStat BazStat
```

However, normalising things like this can be problematic if you want exact pretty-printing later on.

Block statements can be handled similarly:

```
data Stat = … | BlockStat [Stat] | …

-- if (foo) { bar; baz; }
IfStat FooExpr (BlockStat [BarStat, BazStat]) EmptyStat
```

Comment: This echoes what @DanielWagner commented above. But you formalized the answer first, so I will mark your answer as correct. Thanks for the excellent suggestions guys!

Comment: After spending some time looking at this, I think I find the IfStat / IfElseStat the most elegant.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that an `If` *isn't* just an `Else`. You should define something like

```
data If = IfNoElse Expr Statement | IfElse Expr Statement Statement
data Statement = If If | While | ...
```

Comment: if (cond) {} else if {} else {} = `If e s (If e' s' (Else s''))`

Comment: if (cond) {} = `If e s EndIf`

Comment: @kurzweil4 Sure you can. `if(cond) {s} else if(cond') {s'} else {s''}` becomes `If (IfElse cond s (If (IfElse cond' s' s'')))`.

Comment: Proposal: scrap the `If` type entirely and write `data Statement = If Expr Statement (Maybe Statement) | While ... | ...`.

Comment: @DanielWagner After looking at your proposal, I think that is actually excellent.